# changing celery task codebase (autoreload) without killing celery workers

Tags: django, celery

I run a django based web app with celery for background tasks. I'm looking at the issue of deploying new code (or updating virtualenv pip libraries).

The way I see now to deploy new code is to kill celery and start it again. This could lead to killing workers in the middle of a task, leaving the system in an inconsistent state.

Ideally, I would like to be able to deploy new code, let the current workers finish their tasks gracefully and let the new tasks run from the new code.

Seems to me like a very sensible requirement :) how can I do this?
Does the warm shutdown in celery have something to do with this?
I'm killing celery process with `killall -9 celery`

Answer (score 0):

Warm shutdown will usually handle this for you.  You invoke a warm shutdown [by sending `SIGTERM`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#process-signals).